# elasticsearch server is unreachable every 2 hours

Tags: debian, timeout, elasticsearch, 500-error, grafana

This question is related [to this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/399940/17289). We now know that the errors come from elasticsearch. The problems are still not resolved despite the modifications and optimizations made on the es instance. Every 2 hours the es server becomes unreachable: we have timeout or connection reset by peer errors.

We think that is related to this:

[image: elasticsearch translog]

I don't really understand this graph because during the day there is no indexing at all. The index process is only launched once a day at 2 AM and it runs without problem.

I have other Grafana reports, where should I look?

Some data:

[image: grafana]
[image: grafana]

Versions:

- elasticsearch: **1.7.5**

Comment: how many nodes do you have?

Comment: 4. I have updated the question.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's related or not, but isn't 30 shards _way_ to many for 439MB?

Comment: Nothing in the elasticsearch logs? Could you check the kernel ring log (dmesg) or /var/log/syslog to see if it hits a certain limit? Perhaps the maximum number of open file descriptors is reached, too many open connections, not enough HEAP size...

Comment: Please consider getting off 1.7. There are some major issues with stability and data reliability with that version. You may never be able to fix it.

Comment: Check the answer please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have forgotten to answer the question. The issue came form the [F5 load balancer](https://www.f5.com/services/resources/glossary/load-balancer) we were using. After a major upgrade the problem disappeared by itself. We were pretty sure those errors didn't come from the "code". If it can help someone having the same kind of error... Globally this issue was beneficial for the application because, we:

- Cleaned up a lot of code
- Removed an elasticsearch index that was useless
- And more importantly we upgraded elasticsearch from 1.7 to 5.6